# Need help to implement categories in React native app

Tags: react-native

Working on a news app using react native and would like to let users select a news Category on Homepage, with some styles for the active category, how best can I implement this

Comment: Please provide more information, screenshots etc.

Answer (score 0):

if number of categories are not bigger than 20-50 you should use Scrollview, otherwise Flatlist.

```
<ScrollView>
  {categories.map((item) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onClick={yourNavigationFunction}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```